# Mediawiki Documentation - get Article Text

Tags: mediawiki

I am writing an extension for Mediawiki. If I know the page_id and page_title of an article, how do I get the first 50 odd words of the article? Is there a function defined to get the article text give the page_id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like:

```
$article = new Article( Title::newFromText( 'Main_Page' ) ) ;
echo $article->getContent();
```

Grabbing just the first 50 words is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Hey thanks Joshua :) Can you please point me to a link which documents these classes and methods because I have been unable to find any source of information on such crucial functionality anywhere!

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is looking for more documentation, refer to:

http://svn.wikimedia.org/doc/

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want to look at this section of the Bot Wikipedia Page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Creating_a_bot#PHP

The most commented and readable set of classes I have used is http://toolserver.org/~chris/highlight.php?d=chris/classes/&f=botclasses.php

And this can be used in the following way

```
require 'botclasses.php';

$wiki = new wikipedia;
$wiki->url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php';
global $wiki;

$wiki->login("Username","Password");

$text = $wiki->getpage("Wikipedia:Sandbox");
```

Or you can use any of the other functions that are set out in the classes linked above.